# Join To Existing Record In Many to Many Relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, many-to-many

here is the part of EF code-first classes for **Many to Many** relation

```
public class Foo(){
    ....
    public ICollection<Doo> doo { set; get; }
}

public class Doo(){
    ....
    public ICollection<Foo> foo { set; get; }
}
```

EF creates 3 tables in database , `Foo` , `Doo` and join table `FooDoo`

here is my code :

```
var _foo = context.Foo.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.id == fooID);
var _doo = context.Doo.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.id == dooID);
```

how can I set, `_foo` object has many-to-many relation with `_doo` (add fooID and dooID in  `FooDoo` table)

note 1: 
When I use  `_foo.doo.Add(_doo);` EF create a duplicate of `_doo` and then make the relation

Answer (score 0):

In your `DbContext` override you can do something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Doo> Doos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DooConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FooConfiguration());
    }
}

internal class DooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Doo>
{
    public DooConfiguration()
    {
        // your other property mappings here

        HasMany(m => m.Foo)
        .WithMany(m => m.Doo)
        .Map(m => { 
            m.MapLeftKey("fooID"); 
            m.MapRightKey("dooID"); 
            m.ToTable("ManyToManyTableName"); 
        });
    }
}

internal class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        // your other property mappings here

        HasMany(m => m.Doo)
        .WithMany(m => m.Foo)
        .Map(m => { 
            m.MapLeftKey("dooID"); 
            m.MapRightKey("fooID"); 
            m.ToTable("ManyToManyTableName"); 
        });
    }
}
```

Where your `ManyToManyTableName` is of course the database table you'll be storing your many-to-many associations. You are telling which primary keys to return with the `MapLeftKey` and `MapRightKey` associations.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First) has some great further information.

Comment: thank you Terric , this fluent API makes clear relations between `FOO` and `DOO` , in code section 2 , how can I set `doo` object is related to `foo`?!

Comment: @Mironline sorry I'm not sure what you mean - isn't there a many-to-many relation between `foo` and `doo`? This fluent API specifies that, or are you also wanting a one-to-one reference also?